# await on .map throw 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to use async on .map Promise<>[] return
like this:

```
 const teams = await Promise.all(
    helixTeams.map(async helixTeam => {
```

this work ok but following doesn't:

```
 const teams = await helixTeams.map(async helixTeam => {
```

not clear why, if I understand correctly await should always work on Promise return type

Comment: "_if I understand correctly await should always work on Promise return type_" - yes, you understand this correctly, but the return from `.map()`, which you are attempting to `await` is an Array, not a Promise.

Comment: `Promise<Array>` and `Array<Promise>` are different types.